# Epydoc with django

Tags: python, django, documentation-generation

I am trying to generate doc thanks to epydoc.
I wrote the confdoc.txt

My input of modules is from :
C:\Documents and Settings\drale\Desktop\new\project.

I have a mistake : `Could not find a file or object named C:\Documents and Settings\drale\Desktop\new\project.`

This is the path to the project directory containing all my django project.
I think it's because of the space in the path. But i tried with "" and even with three of them, with \, but the same mistake occurs again.

I am working on windows. If you have any idea
Thank you

Comment: This cmd works for me 
`python epydoc --html source_folder -o destination_folder`

Comment: Try entering the path with "/" instead of back-slashes.

Comment: It doesn't work. But what did you put in your epydoc file avasal ?